# Error al instalar moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```py
C:\Users\Pepe>npm install moment
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Pepe\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Pepe\package.json'
npm WARN Pepe No description
npm WARN Pepe No repository field.
npm WARN Pepe No README data
npm WARN Pepe No license field.

+ moment@2.29.1
updated 1 package and audited 2 packages in 1.194s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Hi! this site is in spanish, please translate your question

Comment: Hola que tal, estoy intentando instalar la librería de moment.js, pero me arroja el error indicado

Comment: antes de eso has ejecutado el comando `npm init `??

Comment: si, use npm init, despúes use el comando de npm install moment y me sale este error: Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters.

Comment: Bueno como tal no es un error, solo te dice que no ha podido abrir el `package.json`

Comment: tengo que estar en alguna ruta especifica para poder instalar esta libreria?

Comment: tienes que estra situado en la raiz de tu proyecto tanto al momento de ejecutar `npm init` como cualquier comando de instalación

Comment: muy bien amigo, dejame intentarlo muchas gracias